# Matlab - Modelling Image Formation Algorithm Implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in matlab.

The algorithm (or stages) is as follows:

- (1) Choose an illuminant.
- (2) Calculate colour signals for all the 24 reflectances under that illuminant.
- (3) Multiply, element-by-element, each sensor-response vector (columns or R (see variables)) by the colour signal.
- (4) Sum the result over all wavelengths,(which should leave me with 72 values: 24 R values (one for each surface), 24 G values, and 24 B values)
- (5) Create an image from the calculated sensor response for each reflectance by assigning a 100x100 pixel square and create a pattern of 4 rows and 6
  columns (like a [macbeth colourchecker](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=macbeth%20colorchecker&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=bOb3Upj_MuGV7Aa83IC4Dw&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAg&biw=1074&bih=787)).

I think I'm getting confused at stage 4 (but I might be implementing it wrong earlier)...

These are my variables:

```
   A   %an illuminance vector of size 31x1.
   R   %colour camera sensitivities of size 31x3. (the columns of this matrix are the red, green, and blue sensor response functions of a camera).
   S   %surface reflectances (24) of size 31x24 from a Macbeth ColourChecker (each column is a different reflectance function.
   WAV %Reference wavelength values of size 31x1.
```

This is what I've implemented:

(1)choose A (as it's the only one I've made)

```
  A;
```

(2)Calc colour signals for all 24 reflectances

```
  cSig_1A  = S(:,1).*A;
  cSig_2A  = S(:,2).*A;
         .
         .              %all 24 columns of S
         .
  cSig_24A = S(:,24).*A;
```

(3)multiply sensor-response vector (R columns (RGB)) by colour signal:

```
  % R.*reflectances     G.*reflectances     B.*reflectances     
  a1=R(:,1).*cSig_1A;  a12=R(:,2).*cSig_1A;  a13=R(:,3).* cSig_1A;
  b1=R(:,1).*cSig_2A;  b12=R(:,2).*cSig_2A;  b13=R(:,3).* cSig_2A;
         .
         .              %all 24 signals (think this is correct)
         .
  x1=R(:,1).*cSig_24A; x12=R(:,2).*cSig_24A; x13=R(:,3).*cSig_24A;
```

Assuming I've done the previous steps correct, I'm not sure how you sum the results for this over wavelengths to only have 72 values left? and then create an image from them.

Maybe the wording confuses me but if you guys could give me some guidance, that would be great. It's much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your code of step 2 is wrong... you say all 24 columns of S but you have indexed only the first column. Also, in step 3, you will get 72 values `(a1, a12, a13)->3 values * (cSig_1A,...,cSig_24A) = 3*24 = 72`. If you sum this over cetain variable (in your case, wavelength, which I don't know what it is), won't the values reduce from 72?

Comment: did you mean <<sum the results for this over wavelengths to only have *24* values left>> instead of 72?

Comment: Oops type in step 2. Sorry about this. Corrected. Yes, in step 3 I currently have 72 values... but I don't know what it means by summing, that's where I'm getting confused. Wavelength is just a vector 400:700 which represents the wavelengths of colour I think in our vision. Are you thinking I should sum all the RGB's together (a1+a12+a13)? Thanks for posting.

Comment: You said, reference wavelength is `31x1`? Now you mention that its a vector from 400 to 700, thats `301x1`. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Parag Yes, `WAV` is 31x1 and it's values are `400
   410
   420
   430
   440
   450
   460
   470
   480
   490
   500
   510
   520
   530
   540
   550
   560
   570
   580
   590
   600
   610
   620
   630
   640
   650
   660
   670
   680
   690
   700` I'm unsure of the correct terminology. But it's one column of numbers as shown above. This is why I don't understand the need to multiply it by them, unless it converts them to the correct wavelength or something... Thanks for posting.

Comment: oh ok. They represent wavelengths in `nanometers`. See [here](http://science-edu.larc.nasa.gov/EDDOCS/Wavelengths_for_Colors.html). Yes, now I think that you should sum `(a1+a12+a13)`. I may be wrong though. What you want is a 24 element vector which you can arrange into a `4x6` matrix. So the above operation seems logical. Basically, they mean, sum over all colors. `[a1 a12 a13]` triplet represents a single color. Thus you have 24 colors. That's my understanding.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks Parag, I'll give that a go. Thanks for your time and patience. I'll post back if it's successful :D